# Poincaré group as a topology and a Lie group manifold

Tags: group-theory, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

After some thinking on how to make a topology of the Poincaré group Am not convinced on how it turns out to be in my head : i was thinking about making balls $B_r (w) $ but didn't get much of that, because am not used to this way of thinking. (Butt i reeaaally want to know how to do it).

So i skipped the topology question and switched to the manifold one, I thought of making at first a set $$P(1,3)= \{(L,a)|L\in SO (1,3),a\in R^{3,1}  \}$$ and then an operation $$(L_1,a_1)(L_2,a_2)=(L_2L_1,L_2a_1+a_2)$$
and an inverse $$(L,a)^{-1} =(L^{-1},-L^{-1}a)$$
so the idea was to search for an atlas which i didnt know how to construct, and i find it complex to think of the Poincaré group as two groups.

I also think that my definition of the set is ill defined i think it needs the orthogonality equation of the SO (1,3).

i hope you can help me on this one or give me a book or a YT lecture so i can develop this idea in secure.

Comment: As a set the Poincare group is merely the cartesian product of $SO(1,3)$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$. Since the product of smooth manifolds is again a smooth manifold (with an atlas given by taking the product of each of the charts in the factors atlases). It suffices to show that $SO(1,3)$ is a smooth manifold since $\mathbb{R}^4$ is already a smooth manifold.

Comment: I see what you're trying to tell me, that's convincing but as you know we need a topology to consider that so what topology can I assign to SO(1,3) ?

Comment: $SO(1,3)$ is a subset of $GL(4,\mathbb{R})\subset \mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$ and can be given the subspace topology from $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see that as a set the Poincare group $P=SO(1,3)\rtimes \mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ is the cartesian product $SO(1,3)\times \mathbb{R}^4$. As a topological space, $SO(1,3)$ inherits its topology from $GL(4,\mathbb{R})\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ by the subspace topology; that is $\mathcal{O}_{SO(1,3)}=\{ U\cap SO(1,3)| U\in \mathcal{O}_{GL(4)}\}$, where $\mathcal{O}_{GL(4)}$ is defined using the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$ defined similarly.

We can endow $P$ with a smooth structure by endowing each of its factors $SO(1,3)$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$ with smooth atlases. The closed-subgroup theorem says that if $H\subset G$ is a (topologically) closed subgroup of a Lie group $G$, then $H$ is a Lie group (and hence a smooth manifold). So for our case, it suffices to show that $SO(1,3)$ is a closed subset of $GL(4)$.

Let $(\Lambda_n)$ be a sequence of matrices in $SO(1,3)$ that converge to some matrix $\Lambda\in GL(4)$. For each $n$, $\Lambda_n^T \eta \Lambda_n=\eta$. Since matrix multiplication and the transpose is continuous, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\Lambda_n^T\eta \Lambda_n)=(\lim_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n)^T\eta(\lim_{n\to\infty}\Lambda_n)=\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda$$
Because each of the $\Lambda_n$'s are in $SO(1,3)$, $\Lambda_n^T\eta\Lambda_n=\eta$ for each $n$ and hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\Lambda_n^T\eta \Lambda_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\eta=\eta=\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda$$
Hence $\Lambda\in SO(1,3)$. Since any set subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which contains all of its limit points is closed, $SO(1,3)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$ and therefore a closed subset of $GL(4)$. The closed subgroup theorem then guarantees that $SO(1,3)$ is a Lie subgroup of $GL(4)$ and hence a smooth manifold.

Comment: So if I got it right, you defined a sequence that at its limit to infinity converges in a matrix $\Lambda \in GL(4)$, after that, you used the orthogonality condition proper to the $SO(1,3)$ and showed that if you calculate the limit of this condition you are still going to have the condition verified so the $\Lambda $ is a $SO(1,3)$ matrix. hence the subgroup SO(1,3) is closed; consequently a Lie group.

Comment: That's exactly right!

Comment: that's a great explanation thank you, can I talk with you in private.

Comment: @intelligibleno There is no private messaging on Stack Exchange, but we can talk in the group theory chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80888/group-theory